# How to add subdivision to a collection?

Tags: modeling

I thought there's gotta be a 1 sec way to do it since I come from C4D, but after googling around for half an hour it looks like "link modifier" is the way to do it. Then another half an hour later after I watched a dozen tuts I realised the issue I have now is that the version (Blender3.2) I'm using doesn't have a "Link Modifier" option in the Link menu. How do you guys subD multiple objects now?

Comment: Select all the objects that you want to subdiv and hit Ctrl-1, 2 , 3, etc. depending on the subdiv level you want. (That's the normal number keys, not the numpad ones.)

Comment: Thanks John, but it doesn't work? I'm on Mac so I assume it's Command -1,2,3, and actually I tried all the option/ctrl/shift - 1,2,3 on both normal number keys and numpad keys...none of them works. If you add the subD in this way, will you be able to see the subD surface modifier in the Modifier panel? FYI, I am working on a scene that is imported ABC files, I don't know if it matters. But I can certainly add subD on the mesh manually. I just can't find a way to do them in a batch.

Comment: I've no idea what shortcut you would use on a Mac, but [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#keyboard-shortcuts) is the Blender manual link and it certainly works fine under Windows. Yes, adding it that way adds a modifier to each object which is visible as normal in the modifier panel. Josh sanfelici's method also works fine. There's also a "Copy Modifiers" entry on the Object > Link/Transfer Data menu below the Link entries, but be aware that it will copy **all** the modifiers which are on the source object not just the subdiv.

Answer (score 3):

Well...i can feel your pain because i am working on a MacBook, and i had the same problems. I have no idea who tests the shortcuts on a MacBook at Blender...but they didn't test it on MacBooks - that's for sure.

Fortunately the Blender developers did a great job and you can redefine every shortcut there is as you like (and even more).

So just go to the preferences (which is command + ","), tap on "keymap", and search for "subd" and you got:

[image]

then just tap on the right most button here:

[image]

and then you can enter whatever shortcut you want. As you can see, i chose shift-option-0.

Do the same for the other subdivision values.

After that save your preferences:

[image]

[image]

---

I have no idea whether there was a link modifier menu, but there is a copy modifier menu, so just select all objects, and shift-select the object with your modifier, then press ctrl-L and choose copy modifiers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select one object and add the subdivision modifier, then select all others objects, shift select the modified one last (every object has to be orangy outlined, the one with modifier more yellowish) press Cmd L, choose "Copy modifiers" (or go to menu > object > Link/Transfer Data > Copy modifiers).

If there are more than one modifier and you want to copy only one or some of them, search and enable the "Interface: Copy attribute menu" Addon, make the same kind of selection and press Cmd C, choose "Copy selected modifiers", then in the menu enable the modifiers you want to copy and confirm with OK.

Comment: Yes. That's the 'other' way. :^)